# How to Sum the the column in query to show the result in textbox

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a problem in a query to get the total sum to display it in a textbox in my vb.net form

I have two queries working fine and displaying the result now I want to sum  on of the column of both the queries to display the result in the textbox.

The query is like this

```
Select 
    cl_ccode, co_scode, SUM(im_qty) as invtotal 
from 
    invmast 
where 
    cl_ccode = '3' and co_scode = '271210'
group by 
    cl_ccode, co_scode 

Select 
    cl_ccode, co_scode, SUM(st_qty) as stktotal 
from 
    stock  
where 
    cl_ccode = '3'and co_scode = '271210'
group by 
    cl_ccode, co_scode
```

The output of first query is

```
cl_ccode | co_scode | invtotal
       3 | 271210   | 132200
```

the output of 2nd query is

```
cl_ccode | co_scode | stktotal
       3 |   271210 | 386500
```

I want to display the result after addition invtotal and stktotal which is 518700 in the textbox vb.net

Please guide me how do I get the required result?

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
(
   Select cl_ccode,co_scode, SUM(im_qty)  as invtotal from invmast 
   where cl_ccode='3'and co_scode='271210'
   group by cl_ccode,co_scode 

   union all

   Select cl_ccode,co_scode, SUM(st_qty) as invtotal from stock  
   where cl_ccode='3'and co_scode='271210'
   group by cl_ccode,co_scode 
)

Select sum(invtotal)
from cte
```

Comment: if you can accept this as a answer, that would be great :) @user1797958

Comment: yes thats what i want to do , u really solve my problem , Thanks  again  :) Mukhund

Comment: @user1797958 if you will accpet it, i will get 15 points for that. if this query didn't solve the problem let me know.